# Limitations of Subordination and Nested Clauses

Tags: relative-clauses, clauses, dependent-clause, independent-clauses

I'm an English teacher who often has to grapple with explaining to students the complexity of clause structure in English, and after reading an article about various 'longest sentences' in fiction,  I got to wondering if anyone has ever done any research into the cognitive limitations or constraints on the amount of nesting an average reader can understand. 
That's the basic question: is there any research on what our nested clause comprehension limits are?

But there are loads of related questions that might be relevant here,  too, like: 
How many embedded clauses can you insert in a main clause before the latter element ceases to make sense?
Is there a fixed limit on the amount of nesting we can follow?
How different are English speakers in their ability to track meaning across clauses?

Comment: This may not the right site for your question. But I can recommend _Readability: Text and Context_ (Bailin and Grafstein). In the chapter on _Grammar and Readability: Syntactic complexity_  they cover the issue you raise, without, however, answering the specific questions you ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Susumu Kuno has reported on this in a number of works.  [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&pg=PA328&lpg=PA328&dq=kuno%20clause&source=bl&ots=uPhx9M6CRj&sig=ACfU3U0qjbGqi0Uwwcmvel01rftjiL7JsA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit6eOCvYbhAhX9HzQIHbubAigQ6AEwCXoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=kuno%20clause&f=false) are a few references in McCawley's excellent text on the linguistic analysis of English.